# Camel: Read and Write from the same directory

Tags: java, file, apache-camel, integration

I have this Camel route:

```
final String URI_FILE = "file:{{PATH}}";
final String POOLER = "&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0/10+*+*+*+?";

from(URI_FILE + POOLER)
.pollEnrich().simple("{{URL_CHECKER}}",String.class).aggregationStrategy(new myEstratey())
.choice()
    .when(exchangeProperty("CONTINUE").isEqualTo(true))
        .log("Condition was met")
        .to(URI_DIRECT) //To another route
     .endChoice()
     .otherwise()
        .log("I'll try again later")
        .to(URI_FILE) 
.endChoice();
```

I want read a **file** from **PATH** each **10 minutes**, then check a condition using a pollEnrich. If the condition is met, the route continue. In another case, I want to return the file to the same directory (**PATH**).

This route works ok and even shows the log message "I'll try again later", but after that, the file simply disappears and is not returned to **PATH**

What is happening? It is not allowed to do this in camel?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is most probably overridden in the target directory, but then, after completion, it is moved to `.camel` directory.

It is expected behavior, see [File component docs](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-file/src/main/docs/file-component.adoc):

> Any move or delete operations is executed after (post command) the routing has completed

---

Better rollback your route, it will by default keep file in source directory.

```
final String URI_FILE = "file:{{PATH}}";
final String POOLER = "&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0/10+*+*+*+?";

from(URI_FILE + POOLER)
.pollEnrich().simple("{{URL_CHECKER}}",String.class).aggregationStrategy(new myEstratey())
.choice()
    .when(exchangeProperty("CONTINUE").isEqualTo(true))
        .log("Condition was met")
        .to(URI_DIRECT) //To another route
     .endChoice()
     .otherwise()
        .log("I'll try again later")
        .rollback() // rollback processing and keep file in original directory
.endChoice();
```